# Quantity is getting appended instead of getting added in POST API Tag

Tags: httprequest, robotframework

Below is my Robot Framework code for the POST API:

Create Session    Update_inventory_details

```
${Base_URL}

${body}=    Create Dictionary    distributionPointId=7    menuItemId=1    quantity=1    transactionDoneBy=11    transactionType=1    reasonId=11    barcode=null

${Headers}=    Create Dictionary    Content-Type=application/json    Authorization=bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1c2VyTmFtZSI6InByaXRpc3dhaW4iLCJpYXQiOjE1Njc1MTQ2NDd9.o3qTPbj2KH6AgHpIf1BLV5nOlGL-fR83wSGAYyuWsBQ

${Response}=    Post Request    Update_inventory_details    reportmenuiteminventorychange    data=${body}    headers=${Headers}

Log Many    ${Response.status_code}

Log Many    ${Response.content}
```

${actual_response}=    Convert To String    ${Response.status_code}

Should Be Equal    ${actual_response}    200

On hitting the request via Robot Framework, the quantity tag value is getting appended to the actual quantity.

Example: inventory for item = 1000, adding quantity 1 via API-

Expected inventory = 1001;

Actual inventory = 10001

How do I send value in the quantity tag so that it added and not appended?

```
POSTMAN Request:

{
"distributionPointId":7,
"menuItemId":1,
"quantity":1,
"transactionDoneBy":11,
"transactionType":1,
"reasonId":11,
"barcode":""

}
```

Comment: It looks like you're asking how to get the server to do something different. You appear to be sending the value `1` to the server. Robot has no control over what the server sends back.

Comment: What you're sending as payload through RF is `"quantity":"1"` - the value is a string, due to the way you are creating the dictionary items; in the raw request, I see you're sending `"quantity":1` - the value is an int. To change that, change in the RF call for creating the dict to this - `quantity=${1}`; get back to us if this fixes the issue for you. BTW, this is applicable to all other int values in the payload.

Comment: tried with quantity=${1} and it worked for me.
Thanks.

Comment: Glad it did ;) Working with APIs you should be careful of the payload types, otherwise it may cause bugs like this one.

Comment: Indeed it leads to such silly bugs and these rather take much time for debugging. Thanks for your prompt replies. :) Really Appreciate that